# Why can't I translate an image?

Tags: html, css, graphics

I have some html images I want to display in 3D:

```
<div class="col-9">
    <div class="Flipper">
        <img src="static/images/drapes.png" class="projectFrame Flipper-inner" id="img1">

        <img src="static/images/drapes.png" class="projectFrame Flipper-inner" id="img2">

        <img src="static/images/drapes.png" class="projectFrame Flipper-inner" id="img3">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I try to modify it with CSS to stack multiple images on top of one another like this:

```
.Flipper {
    margin-top: 10%;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: flex;
}

.Flipper-inner {
    transform: rotateY(80deg);
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#img2 {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate3d(-200px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: rotateY(80deg);
}
```

However no matter what I do the images remain static

Comment: Your image gets [*correctly transformed*](http://jsfiddle.net/023mjxwg/). If you have a 2D image, naturally you can't get *more* image data out of it by simply transforming it. That is to say, you can't simply turn a 2D image into a 3D one. Are you asking how you can add a transition, like a card flip effect?

Comment: I don't want to get more out of it. I want to move the image. Like the image exists on a plane. That plane was rotated 30 degrees, I now want to translate that plane 200 pixels to the left.

Comment: If you notice in the link you sent, modifying the number of pixels in translate does not affect the position of the images

Comment: Are you looking for an effect like [*this*](http://jsfiddle.net/rv5Lq3xn/), where one image sits on top of another? To achieve that, just use `margin-left` and set your `z-index` values in the order you want :)

Comment: The tranlated image stops being rotated however. I need them to be non-rotated.

Comment: You have two `transform` prop\rties on the image; the second one replaces the first, obliterating the `translate3d`..